# Вывод ленты новостей с датой за сегодня, вчера и т.д

Tags: php

Сделал вывод ленты заголовков новостей с выводом даты, таким образом:

```
14:28 Заголовок новости
11:43 Заголовок новости
10:21 Заголовок новости
```

и т.д.

Но как сделать вывод даты так, чтобы, если новость опубликована скажем вчера в 23:10, писалось типа такого:

```
14:28 Заголовок новости
11:43 Заголовок новости
10:21 Заголовок новости
27 июня, 23:10 Заголовок новости
27 июня, 22:36 Заголовок новости
```

и т.д.

Как это сделать? Дата в поле date в формате 1561712237

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
$formatOut = (date('Ymd',$NewsDate)==date('Ymd',time()))?'H:i':'d M, H:i';
echo "news posted at: ".date($formatOut,$NewsDate);
```

Утащено с первого попавшегося сайта:

```
function rdate($param, $time=0) {
    if(intval($time)==0)$time=time();
    $MonthNames=array("Января", "Февраля", "Марта", "Апреля", "Мая", "Июня", "Июля", "Августа", "Сентября", "Октября", "Ноября", "Декабря");
    if(strpos($param,'M')===false) return date($param, $time);
        else return date(str_replace('M',$MonthNames[date('n',$time)-1],$param), $time);
}
```

Тогда код будет выглядеть так:

```
$formatOut = (date('Ymd',$NewsDate)==date('Ymd',time()))?'H:i':'d M, H:i';
echo "news posted at: ".rdate($formatOut,$NewsDate);
```

Comment: Работает идеально!

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как вставить вместо месяца Jan по русски Январь скажем, июнь и т.д.?

Comment: Обновил ответ, пробуйте

Comment: Все круто пашет, спасибо!)